# Error Class Cake\Mailer\TransportFactory does not have a property named _config

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to create a New Cakephp 4.5 project, but every time I create a new one, then start the server, it gives me the error

```
Class Cake\Mailer\TransportFactory does not have a property named _config
```

I'm not changing the code after creating the project, just try to cake server and it happens, even if i create another project with another name in another folder, the error keeps happening.

Comment: What line of code is this happening at? Stack trace? What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded my php to version 8.0.3, now my new projects are working properly.